# Windows Phone app consuming excessive battery. Using HttpClient

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm coding an app that allow users to control Media Classic Player (MPC) playback, such as Pause/Play, Volume Up/down, syncing subtitle, etc. MPC has a Web Interface that can be activated to make this interaction easier. But sometimes when I run and use the app, my battery runs out faster than usual.

A critical feature that I'm pretty sure that is causing this excessive consume of battery is the timer. Code is below this description, but to make it short, after some seconds, it repeats the `HttpClient` request to the Web Interface to receive the correct current time of player.

**My question is**: Am I right thinking that `HttpClient` behavior could be generating excessive requests and stacking then even if the App is not running anymore? And, if `HttpClient` isn't the right or the better object to use and interact with a web server, what would it be? Suggestions of what I should know about requests in C# are welcome (methods, objects, books about theses objects, etc)

The app runs in a file named **MainPage.cs**. It uses methods of a class named **Player.cs**.

**MainPage.cs**:

```
namespace homecinemarc
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        public IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
        // Timer to check movie status is defined here
        public DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(.3) };
        public HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        private Player player;
        private string filename;

        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            // Default initialization
            InitializeComponent();

            if (settings.Contains("ip") && settings.Contains("port"))
            {
                player = new Player(settings["ip"] as string, settings["port"] as string);
            }

            if (!DeviceNetworkInformation.IsWiFiEnabled)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Your phone's wifi is off. To run this app correctly, you must turn it on. You will be redirected to you Windows Phone connectivity settings.");
                ConnectionSettingsTask connectionSettingsTask = new ConnectionSettingsTask();
                connectionSettingsTask.ConnectionSettingsType = ConnectionSettingsType.WiFi;
                connectionSettingsTask.Show();
            }


            // Default Messaging
            connectedMessage.Text = "Connecting to homecinema";
            progressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;           
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Core code
        /// </summary>
        private async void MainProgram()
        {
            if (await player.checkConnection())
            {

                connectedMessage.Text = "Connected to " + player.ip + ":" + player.port;
                PlayButton.IsEnabled = true;
                PauseButton.IsEnabled = true;

                // Verificar posição do player
                await player.checkStatus();

                // Update with player status;
                barPosition.Maximum = player.totalTime.Ticks;
                barPosition.Value = player.currentTime.Ticks;

                txtCurrentTime.Text = player.currentTime.ToString();
                txtTotalTime.Text = player.totalTime.ToString();

                if (player.status == "Playing")
                {
                    PauseButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    PlayButton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                }
                else
                {
                    PauseButton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    PlayButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                }

                timer.Tick += updateTimers;
                timer.Start();
            }
            else
            {
                player.showError(Error.FailedToConnect);
                connectedMessage.Text = "Connection Failed to " + player.ip + ":" + player.port;
            }
            progressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Checks if it's the first run of the app.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            // First run, runs a basic configuration.
            if (!settings.Contains("firstRun"))
            {
                try
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("This is your first run! Let me show how to setup Homecinema correctly. You must tap on Settings by the end of the instructions, set an IP and save it to use this app correctly :)");
                    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/HelpPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MainProgram();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Update timer values
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private async void updateTimers(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await player.checkStatus();

            string currentFilename = player.filename;

            // Checks if there is a change of file and reset 
            // subtitle delay value if there is.
            if (filename != currentFilename)
                player.subtitleDelay = 0;

            barPosition.Value = player.currentTime.Ticks;
            txtCurrentTime.Text = player.currentTime.ToString();
            txtStatus.Text = player.status;
            txtVolume.Text = player.volumeValue + "%";
            txtVolume.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
            txtFilename.Text = player.filename;
            txtSubtitleValue.Text = player.subtitleDelay + "ms";
            filename = player.filename;

            if (player.volumeMute == 1)
            {
                txtVolume.Text = "Mute";
                txtVolume.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            }

            if (player.status == "Playing")
            {
                PlayButton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                PauseButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
            else
            {
                PauseButton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                PlayButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }

        }

        /********************************
         * Events 
         ********************************/

        private void Refresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            connectedMessage.Text = "Connecting to homecinema";
            progressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

            MainProgram();
        }

        private void Play_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            player.makeRequest("887");
            txtStatus.Text = "Playing";
            timer.Start();
            PlayButton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            PauseButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }

        private void Pause_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            player.makeRequest("888");
            txtStatus.Text = "Paused";
            PauseButton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            PlayButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }

        private void btn_volumeMute_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            player.makeRequest("909");
        }

        private void btnVolumeUp_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            player.makeRequest("907");
        }

        // There are some other events but all with the same structure as
        // above.

    }
}
```

**Player.cs**:

```
namespace homecinemarc
{
    class Player
    {
        public Connection conn;
        public string ip { get; set; }
        public string port { get; set; }
        public string filename { get; private set; }
        public string status { get; private set; }
        public int volumeValue { get; private set; }
        public int volumeMute { get; private set; }
        public bool isConnected { get; private set; }
        public TimeSpan currentTime;
        public TimeSpan totalTime;
        public int subtitleDelay { get; set; }
        private HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        // Constructor
        public Player(string ip, string port)
        {
            conn = new Connection(ip, port);
            this.ip = ip;
            this.port = port;
            this.subtitleDelay = 0;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Check if there is a connection to defined IP and Port to allow the app to run
        /// </summary>
        public async Task<bool> checkConnection()
        {
            try
            {
                HttpResponseMessage aResponse = await client.GetAsync(new Uri("http://" + ip + ":" + port + "/command.html"));
                isConnected = aResponse.StatusCode.Equals(HttpStatusCode.OK);
                return isConnected;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Update variables of timers 
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public async Task checkStatus()
        {
            HttpResponseMessage aResponse = await client.GetAsync(new Uri("http://" + this.ip + ":" + this.port + "/status.html"));
            string[] match = Regex.Split(aResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result, @",");

            if (match.Length > 0){
                TimeSpan.TryParse(match[3].Substring(2, match[3].Length - 3), out currentTime);
                TimeSpan.TryParse(match[5].Substring(2, match[5].Length - 3), out totalTime);
                status = match[1].Substring(2, match[1].Length - 3);
                volumeMute = int.Parse(match[6]);
                volumeValue = int.Parse(match[7]);

                // These next steps try to remove Rippers, file formarts, etc
                // to show a short yet useful name. That's because MPC don't
                // return the media title (like, IDv3 tag), just filename.
                match[0] = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(match[0]);
                match[0] = Regex.Replace(match[0].Substring(12, match[0].Length - 15), "[\\.]|[\\+]", " ");
                match[0] = Regex.Replace(match[0], "Xvid|Ac3|www|org|avi|mp4|mkv|wmv|HDTV|X264|DIMENSION|\\-|\\((\\d+)\\)|%5(d|b)|Dual Audio|BRRip|x264|AC3|1080p|Lektor i Napisy PL|mvgroup|NF|DD5|WEBRip|NTb|\\-", "");

                filename = match[0];
                Debug.WriteLine(filename);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Core method that sends POST request to IP and PORT defined
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="wmcommand">Code defined by MCP controls.html code</param>
        public async void makeRequest(String wmcommand)
        {
            try
            {
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                var body = String.Format("wm_command={0}", wmcommand);

                StringContent theContent = new StringContent(body, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                HttpResponseMessage aResponse = await client.PostAsync(new Uri("http://" + this.ip + ":" + this.port + "/command.html"), theContent);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                showError(Error.FailedRequest);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Shoes a messagebox with error description
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="error">Error type of sealed values. Seek to Error class to find which is appropriate</param>
        public void showError(Error error)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(error.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just temporarily replace the frequent web requests with a mocked response from a string? How does that affect perf? From you description, it seems unlikely that it's the web requests causing a perf problem compared to something doing media playback.

Comment: @WiredPrairie The app does not control media playback of a media from the phone itself. It's used to control a remote player, a PC on my living room for example, with no keyboard/mouse. The app goal is to replace a remote control with MPC playback controls. A mocked string would lose synchronism with the player, if user stops the media by keyboard and not by app, it would continue to counting.

Comment: I'm not sure how to help if you can't temporarily replace the web service calls.  Have you tried using a profiler to see if there's unexplained CPU usage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was working on another project that consists in to a timer running background. For my surprise, I learned that a app, when `suspended`, that is, when the lock screen come down or other app start to running, all connections, webrequests or timers stop until the user come back to the app, and it won't automatically retry connections and requests if not coded to do so.

This could be a problem if I had set `PhoneApplicationService.Current.UserIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;`, which would override user's settings and prevent lock screen and then I would have to manually handle all timers and requests to be on hold - ([Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff941090%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)).

Finally, this app is not the problem, neither is `HttpClient` object.